# Porting date formatting from Java to C++

Tags: java, c++, porting

I have the following code in Java. I've been asked to port it to C++, however, I am not a Java developer. What would be the equivalent in C++:

```
public String formatDate( String string, Date time, TimeZone timeZone )
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance( timeZone );
    calendar.setTime( time );
    StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( string );
    format.format( calendar, answer, null );
    return answer.toString();
}
```

The following line is how it's being called:

```
formatDate( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", new Date(), TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ));
```

The format string has 'T' and 'Z', which I cannot find much documentation on.

Comment: With a single quote `'T'` is a string literal. In fact "2012-11-13T23:59..." is the international ISO standard for a data-time value, T standing for Time (an anglicism).

Comment: +1 for mentioning ISO standard. In fact it's the ISO 8601 standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T and Z are simply being inserted (note the quotes) and *not* being replaced as part of the formatting. Thus the above could give you

```
2012-11-13T14:35Z
```

The Z would normally give you a time zone (e.g. `+0000`) if it wasn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) gives you a list of the formatting options. `Z` normally stands for the timezone, note however that both `Z` and `T` are actually `'Z'` and `'T'`, they're just Strings.